# change the field type

Tags: carto

I want to change the field type of a varchar to a date, but being synchronized does not leave me. The text format is 2018-01-01T14: 00: 00Z

When I try to change it in sql it gives me a bug:

```
ALTER TABLE executed_def_2018 alter column horafinejec type date;
```

And when I synchronized, I would pass it back to text. I wanted to know the best solution

Comment: Which database are you using? What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** change the schema of a CARTO sync table because they are read-only, since every time the sync happens the table is replaced. So it really depends on what you have to do with that field.

If the table is not very big you can just cast the field on a query using [to_date](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html) function directly on BUILDER or any other map instantiation.

If the dataset is big and you are using BUILDER you can put a `Subsample` analysis with a 100% of your rows to "cache" the table on your account.

If your dataset is big but you are not using BUILDER, I would recommend creating a [materialized view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html), but then you need to remember to create the proper indexes so your queries perform **and** remember to refresh your view after your syncs.

Edit: if you have `NULL` values `to_date` should ignore them properly, but still if you want to provide a default date for those rows you can use `coalesce` this way:

[image]

Comment: THE TO_DATE FUNCTION PERFECTLY EXCEPTING WHEN IN THE FIELD THAT I WANT TO TRANSFORM I HAVE NULL VALUES. the message is:
THE VALUE << >> IS NOT VALID FOR 'yyyy' THE VALUE MUST BE A WHOLE.
I WANTED TO KNOW HOW I CAN MAKE DISCRIMINATION OF THE NULL

Comment: added a comment about null values, no need to use uppercase mate :)